# How to ignore SQL Query part of WHERE conditionally in JPA Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am wondering if it is possible to ignore part of query (not whole where part) conditionally. I have query in JPA

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT new it.akademija.wizards.models.document.DocumentGetReviewCommand(" +
        "d.author.firstname, d.author.lastname, d.id, d.title, d.description, d.documentType.title, d.submissionDate)" +
        " FROM Document d" +
        " JOIN d.documentType dt" +
        " JOIN dt.reviewUserGroups rug" +
        " JOIN rug.users u WHERE u.username = :username" +
        " AND d.documentState = it.akademija.wizards.enums.DocumentState.SUBMITTED" +
        " AND u <> d.author" +
        " **AND (lower(CONCAT(d.author.firstname, ' ', d.author.lastname)) like %:searchFor% " +
        " OR lower(d.title) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(d.description) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(d.id) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(dt.title) like %:searchFor%)")
   Page<DocumentGetReviewCommand> getDocumentsForReview(@Param(value = "username") String username,
                                                     @Param(value = "searchFor") String searchFor,
                                                     Pageable pageable);
```

How can I ignore below part if searchFor param is null or blank ("")

```
AND (lower(CONCAT(d.author.firstname, ' ', d.author.lastname)) like %:searchFor% " +
        " OR lower(d.title) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(d.description) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(d.id) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(dt.title) like %:searchFor%)
```

Comment: FYI That is JPQL, not SQL, and that is Spring Data JPA not the JPA API

Answer (score 0):

You could just try adding logic which allows these conditions to be skipped should the search for term be null or empty:

```
AND
    (COALESCE(:searchFor, '') = '' OR
    (LOWER(CONCAT(d.author.firstname, ' ', d.author.lastname)) LIKE %:searchFor% OR
     LOWER(d.title) LIKE %:searchFor%" OR
     LOWER(d.description) LIKE %:searchFor% OR
     LOWER(d.id) LIKE %:searchFor% OR
     LOWER(dt.title) like %:searchFor%))
```